# Why does my VirtualBox application not show at Command key / VirtualBox?

Tags: gnome

Most of my applications are available with "Windows" key followed by the first few letters of the program name.  VirtualBox does not do that. I installed it using the downloaded deb file.  It runs fine, but i always have to open a terminal to start it.  (Ubuntu 14.04.2 Gnome 3)

Comment: As they say on The I.T. Croud, "Switch it off and switch it on again".  I rebooted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop ?
If you don't try creating one. Mine looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VirtualBox
GenericName=PC virtualization solution
Comment=Run several virtual systems on a single host computer
Comment[de]=Mehrere virtuelle Maschinen auf einem einzigen Rechner ausführen
Comment[it]=Esegui più macchine virtuali su un singolo computer
Comment[pl]=Uruchamianie wielu systemów wirtualnych na jednym komputerze gospodarza
Comment[sv]=Kör flera virtuella system på en enda värddator
Comment[ko]=가상 머신
Type=Application
Exec=VirtualBox %U
TryExec=VirtualBox
MimeType=application/x-virtualbox-vbox;application/x-virtualbox-vbox-extpack;application/$
Icon=virtualbox
Categories=Emulator;Utility;
```

Comment: I do have that file.  It is only slightly different from yours, but has all of the entries.